# Does a split plot design require a different type of coding for Tukey's HSD than a simpler design?

Tags: r, tukey

I used the search function and was surprised to have not found anything on this. I am familiar with writing code in R for Tukey's HSD for other experimental designs, but does anything need to be changed if it's for a split plot design? When I type the code I used for a simpler experimental design, I get a response that is not what I wanted.

For reference, this is the head of my data. I can share more if needed:

```
 dput(head(rawData))
structure(list(ï..Plot = 2111:2116, Variety = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Burbank", "Hodag", "Lamoka", 
"Norkotah", "Silverton", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), Rate = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), totalTubers = c(594L, 
605L, 656L, 729L, 694L, 548L), totalOzNoCulls = c(2544.18, 2382.07, 
2140.69, 2401.56, 2440.56, 2503.5), totalCWTacNoCulls = c(461.76867, 
432.345705, 388.535235, 435.88314, 442.96164, 454.38525), avgLWratio = c(1.260615419, 
1.287949374, 1.111981583, 1.08647584, 1.350686661, 1.107173509
), Hollow = c(14L, 15L, 22L, 25L, 14L, 13L), Double = c(10L, 
13L, 15L, 22L, 11L, 9L), Knob = c(86L, 80L, 139L, 156L, 77L, 
126L), Researcher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Wang", class = "factor"), 
    CullsPounds = c(1.75, 1.15, 4.7, 1.85, 0.8, 5.55), CullsOz = c(28, 
    18.4, 75.2, 29.6, 12.8, 88.8), totalOz = c(2572.18, 2400.47, 
    2215.89, 2431.16, 2453.36, 2592.3), totalCWTacCulls = c(466.85067, 
    435.685305, 402.184035, 441.25554, 445.28484, 470.50245)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am interested in seeing the different letter categories for the different Rates. I would like to put them over a plot that has a bar graph for each Variety (six in total) with totalCWTacCulls on the y axis and the 5 Rates on each of the x axis

Here is the anova I would use for this data:

```
require(agricole)
model <- with(rawData, sp.plot(Rep, Rate, Variety, totalCWTacCulls))
```

And here is how I write out my Tukey's HSD test:

```
TukeyAOV <- aov(totalCWTacCulls ~ Rep + Rate, data=rawData)
summary(TukeyAOV)
HSD <- HSD.test(TukeyAOV, "Rate", alpha = 0.05, group=TRUE)
print(HSD$groups)
```

However, this gives me information that I was not expecting:

```
  totalCWTacCulls groups
1        469.5366      a
2        469.4445      a
5        461.2242      a
3        456.3787      a
4        451.1329      a
```

Any help as to what I'm doing wrong and what I could do differently would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!